# Global Payments, converting a single payment token to multi payment token

Tags: global-payments-api

I'm integrating the Global Payments API using the .NET SDK and hosted fields.
I've generated an API access token for the hosted payment fields using the permission "PMT_POST_Create_Single".
The access token is created successfully and the hosted fields are working as expected. The user enters in some Credit Card info and the Global Payments API returns a 'single use payment token'.

I need to convert the single payment token to a multi use (multi payment) token for our business use case.

1. How do you convert a single payment token to a multi use token?
2. What permissions do I need to set on the API access token to allow
   this?
3. What is the API call to make the conversion?
4. Does the .NET SDK have a function call for this?